# Is it possible to reference a list item without explicitly using indices in python?

Tags: python, list, reference

I am wondering if there is a way to reference a list element without using `some_list[n]`, this is what I mean:

```
def foo(element_list):
    for i, element in enumerate(element_list):
        if i < len(element_list)-1:
            print(element_list[i], element)

array = [25, 21, 22, 24, 23, 27, 26]
foo(array)
```

`element` and `element_list[i]` are the same (because they are referencing the same `int` object in this case), hence the `id(element)` is equal to `id(element_list[i]`, but

`element = 1` is not equal to `element_list[i] = 1`. So the list item is copied, not referenced. Is it possible to reference it so the latter becomes equal?

I understand that `enumerate()` creates new object.

Comment: In short, no. That’s not how assignment works in Python.

Comment: "element = 1 is not equal to element_list[i] = 1. So the list item is copied, not referenced." Um, no the list item is *never* copied.

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: This is same as `a = [1, 2]; b = a;` now `a`, `b` will have same `id` but now do `b = [3, 4]`...`a` is not mutated. `a` and `b` are simply just names attached to object in memory. When you do `b = a` now object([1, 2] in memory) has two names attached to it. `b = [3, 4]` now simply `b` is name of `[3, 4]`

Comment: It is not possible to assign to an index in a list without in *some* fashion doing `mylist[index] = whatever`

Comment: @Ch3steR thanks for this, and to everyone else also. I will look into the given link